# Folder in root greyed out in Finder but accessible in Terminal

Tags: finder, permission

I've just migrated from an old MBP to a new one. I had a folder `Transmachina` in the root in which I keep a large SVN working copy. I just copied this over with `cp -R` but on the new machine this folder is greyed out in Finder, and I can't navigate into it.

In terminal, I can access it fine as my user (no `sudo`) and the permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   56 nic   wheel    Transmachina
```

which are the same as on the old machine. Both are running 10.8.2, but the old machine was 10.5 when originally purchased and configured.

Update: `xattr -l Transmachina` doesn't show anything at all.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Does `xattr -l` show any extended attributes?

Comment: What is the name of the folder?

Comment: I've updated the question with the folder name "Transmachina" - it's not a reserved name or anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer here: http://stephenmonro.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/the-best-file-management-utility-for-mac-osx/

Use a command like this on the folder:

`SetFile -d 06/13/2011 PATH/`

Comment: Thanks! To be fair the author found the solution at http://macadmins.psu.edu/news/2011/06/grayed_out_finder_folder

Comment: Especially since the original link has disappeared, it's worth pointing out that the SetFile command is part of the XCode command-line tools.